# Find an error message after installing ggfortify at conda environment when call the library from JupyterLab of this conda kernel

Tags: r, jupyter-lab, miniconda, ggfortify

I have install conda and create a conda environment of R. Then I have add this r-env to jupyterLab as a kernel.

From terminal of activated r-env I have installed ggfortify R package using "conda install -c conda-forge r-ggfortify -y". And succesfully installed. Then restart my jupyter kernel and added r-env kernel. But when i call the library at the jupyter cell, I have found a error. My R version: 4.2.3

Error:

````
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggfortify’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/preonath/miniconda3/envs/ir/lib/R/library/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback:

1. library(ggfortify)
2. tryCatch({
 .     attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
 .     ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 .     env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps, exclude, include.only)
 . }, error = function(e) {
 .     P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
 .         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
 .     else ""
 .     msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", 
 .         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
 .     if (logical.return && !quietly) 
 .         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
 .     else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
 . })
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. value[[3L]](cond)
6. stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)

I have also tried to install without conda.. 

```R consol
# CRAN
"install.packages("ggfortify")" 

Warning message:
In install.packages("ggfortify") :
  installation of package 'ggfortify' had non-zero exit status


I have also used the source file to install.
After downloading ggfortify_0.4.16.tar.gz at Downloads. Then 
setwd("~/Downloads")

Warning message:
In install.packages("ggfortify_0.4.16.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source") :
  installation of package 'ggfortify_0.4.16.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status

How i can call the ggfortify package from JupyterLab cell without any error?
````